# Can I Mock arguments in Python mock?

Tags: python, testing, mocking

I have a mocked function `synchronize`  and I want that whenever its called it is called its with specific argument

With side_effect and return_function I can only modify value that is returned. Is there a way to do this?

```
@patch('synchronize')
def test1(_synchronize):
      _synchronize.return_value = None
```

Comment: I think that you are misleading with the concepts. As you mock the method, you can call it with any param, it will return the value you've mocked.